# NVDA + FF - Not working as expected in Modal

Tags: firefox, accessibility, nvda

I am opening Modal and shifting focus to close button that in top right on the modal, if I hit immediately enter then it is closing the Modal properly but if I stay for sometime meanwhile NVDA start reading modal heading and content, then I hit enter then Modal is not closing even though focus is still on the close button.

Modal popup should close immediately as well.

Comment: Would you be able to share some code? If after a while NVDA starts reading through the document, maybe that’s configurable behaviour and actually correct. We’d need to hear it from an actual NVDA user. When it starts reading, and you use _Tab_ again, are you able to focus the close button again?